# JUnit @RepeatedTest for concurrent execution

Tags: java, performance, testing, junit, concurrency

I've read [following article](http://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-repeated-test) and I understand that I can ask junit to execute test several times by adding following annotation:

```
@RepeatedTest(value = 3, name = RepeatedTest.LONG_DISPLAY_NAME)
```

But I want to start these 3 time in parallel.
Is it posssible?

`P.S.` I want to check that tests pass correctly for 10+ threads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowadays this is possible by leveraging the (experimental) [Parallel Execution](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution) feature. For this you need to add a `junit-platform.properties` file to your test resource directory. You also need to add the `@Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)` to your tests. See the examples below:

junit-platform.properties:

```
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled = true
junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent
```

Test

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.parallel.Execution;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.parallel.ExecutionMode;

class ParallelRepeatTest {

    @Execution(ExecutionMode.CONCURRENT)
    @RepeatedTest(10)
    void testVilocDecodingWithSabotagedFalse_usingMqttPlug() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

If you need to tweak the threading settings, refer to the junit5 documentation linked above.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible currently with JUnit 5.

There is an ongoing discussion on this feature: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/60.

You could use [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/) to achive concurrent execution this with `invocationCount` and `threadPoolSize` parameters for `@Test`. Like this:

```
@Test(invocationCount=10, threadPoolSize=4)
public void shouldWork() {
    // test body
}
```