# Best way to setup Test with 10 Threads that firing API Request?

Tags: java, testing, junit, quarkus, gatling

I need to setup  1 test that spawns 10 Threads where each fires a request to the same REST Api.
First I think it's not possbile to model real paralellism . In Java you cannot say thread1 should run on core1 and thread2 should run on core2 etc. But in Java it is possible to create Thread e.g. with fork/join framework or just with Runnable etc.

In our test scenario with 10 requests , 5 should return HTTP Status 200 and 5 should return 4xx HTTP Status so we know our locks etc works.

So should I just use Java native classes or Quarkus native classes or should I use a framwork like Gatlin which I have no idea of.

As I said it's just this 1 testcase and I ask myself if it's worth to burden our projekt with a new framework.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [TestNG](https://testng.org/), that supports parallel and configurable tests:

```java
@Test(threadPoolSize = 10, inmvocationCount=20, timeOut = 10000)
public void yourTest(){
  // …
}
```

Comment: Is that also possible with JUnit because in our 3 year old project we are not unsing TestNG

Comment: Currently TestNG is not supported by Quarkus. See: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2510

Comment: I think I could implement my scenario using Java Completeable Future with CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...,executor)

Comment: Junit 5 has support for `@RepeatedTest`, maybe you should have a look at that.

Comment: @Serkan, `@RepeatableTest` works like a simple loop. It runs test N-times in the single thread. It is a good tool if you would like to spot some simple issues with memory leaks, or "load" some service to a specific level.

Comment: @Koziołek, have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49005104/junit-repeatedtest-for-concurrent-execution